# Amazon private key, where should I store it?

Tags: amazon-web-services

According to [Amazon docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html) I should "Save [my] private key file in a safe place."

I am using a Mac book pro. What is a "safe" place to store this? Should I store it with the rest of my .ssh keys?

Answer (score 1):

By safe place AWS means a location which is not accessible by public or any one else. So you can store it with your other SSH keys if you are sure your MAC is well protected.

Also I will suggest to keep a backup of all the keys some were in encrypted cloud storage just in case your MAC crashes or get stolen or some thing like that. Because it becomes a really pain to get access to the AWS resources that are tied to those keys if the keys are lost.

Answer (score 0):

1. Follow the advice in the answer by @error2007s.
2. Copy to a fresh flash drive (nothing else on it, they are cheap), put the flash drive in an envelope and write on the envelop what it is, flash drives not in envelops may easily be misplaced or re-used, put it to in your safe.
3. Print it out and put the printout in your safe, this is the "if-all-else-fails" copy.

Really, get a fire-proof safe, if possible not a cheap Office Supply safe that pops open when dropped on a corner.